# if god is there why is there suffering?

Tags: theology, meaning-of-life

Whenever I look around myself and see suffering I
 feel god cannot be real.If god is real then why is there so much suffering and poverty?

Comment: See [Theodicy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodicy) and [Leibniz on the Problem of Evil](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz-evil/).

Comment: Welcome to the site, daboss.  While this is a great philosophical question, it is way too big, and there is too little agreement on the answer, for us to handle in this forum.  You might try asking what some famous philosophers have said about this question, or what the dominant theological answers to this are, or what a particular philosopher or religion teaches.

Comment: You may be able to edit this question and get it reopened by turning this into a reference request.  The question you ask is tremendously famous, with many many answers from different philosophers.

Comment: It cannot be properly explained here but for Buddhists both God and suffering would be unreal. This view can be tweaked (or the words can be tweaked) to allow God to be real and suffering to be unreal. This would answer your question but it would not be my answer. My answer would be that your idea of God is incompatible with suffering so does not survive analysis, and that a better idea is required.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is suffering because we call it suffering. If we really dont know the roots of the problems, we tend to interpret them in an evil manner or call it as disaster or suffering, but in an Islamic point of view, there is suffering because there would be no growth without it like the case of Abraham that wanted to sacrifice his son or the case of Khezr that killed a child and broke a ship but all under God's command so that there were no problem.
So suffering is not sth concrete and stable that we can rely on for philosophical discourse. All of us have changed our attitudes toward it since our childhood.
So this question wont have any answer unless one answers this one first : What is suffering?

Comment: Equally, we could ask: Who is suffering?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of suffering is somewhat separate from the problem of existence.

For a god to end suffering that god would need to:

1. know about the suffering
2. be able to do something about the suffering
3. be willing to do something about the suffering

If god is missing one of these traits then they could still exist but not be able to prevent suffering.

Now, whether or not it makes sense to worship a being that is missing one or all of these traits is a somewhat different question.

BTW this is often dealt with using the concepts of omniscience, omnipresence, omnipotence and benevolence. However, a god doesn't need these in order to end suffering. For example, I'm aware of the suffering but don't have omniscience.

Comment: I think the issue op has may be with the Christian god, which is supposed to have all three of those qualities, yet does not stop suffering.

Comment: @Braydon I'm sure you're right but the denomination wasn't specified in the question (at least at the time I wrote this answer) so I kept the answer more general. Of course, if your god doesn't profess to benevolence then the analysis still stands but is a bit pointless.

Comment: How is "I'm aware of the suffering but don't have omniscience." an example for "However, a god doesn't need these in order to end suffering."? Did you not tell us something about you? ;)

Comment: @SK19 you don’t need omniscience in order to know about suffering. You just need to know about the suffering. These, overarching traits aren’t necessary for the ending of suffering. Handy, sure, but not necessary.